# What is the right way to manually install package in macOS Sierra

Tags: packages, installing, mac

I would like to manually install `\usepackage{emerald}` in my macOS Sierra. In my Windows OS, Miktex does a good job via install-on-fly feature but this is not the case with Tex live. A suggested GUI for this matter is [tex live utility](http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/) but I've downloaded it and Xcode throws some errors. I don't have enough time to debug it, so I'm looking for the right way to manually install a package in Sierra. I've searched for how to download packages manually but the posts describe old versions of Mac (i.e. paths don't exist in my OS). The only post worked is this [How do I install a LaTeX .sty file on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390828/how-do-i-install-a-latex-sty-file-on-osx) but the font  in the following code is not generated. I suspect the way packaged installed since the font is generated in my Windows OS but unfortunately my laptop is at computer repair shop and I'm forced to use my Mac.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\ECFWebster Results 
\end{document}
```

The expected output is

[image]

But in my Mac, the output is

[image]

Comment: Is there any error or warning in the Log?  It seems, as if they font itself isn't installed on your Mac.

Comment: I get these warnings `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'T1/fwb/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using 'T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 7.

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./main.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`

Comment: This points into my first direction.  Your TeX-system was not able to find the font fwb, which is defined by the package `emerald`.

Answer (score 1):

First download the emerald.zip file from CTAN and un-zip it. Then download the `TeXLive2014+Changes.pdf.zip' document from <https://herbs.github.io> and look at the section on installing fonts

Comment: I've created `updmap.cfg` and typed `Map emerald.map` with a black new line.  I don't have this folder `texmf-local/fonts/map` I just created it and place `emerald.sty` inside it. I run `sudo -H mktexlsr` and `sudo -H updmap-sys` . I still get this `LaTeX Error: File 'emerald.sty' not found.`

Comment: In Terminal change directory (cd) to /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local and work from there. If you don't like to use Terminal click on the Go menu in Finder and the the Go To Folder... item. Then enter /usr/local/texlive and press Return to open that folder in Finder. You can then work from there.

Comment: I got these errors `updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:  emerald.map (in /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?`

Comment: As the document says, if you put the files in the /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local root you need to run `sudo -H updmap-sys` rather than `updmap`. After you do that you'll now have to delete ~/Library/texlive/2016. To open ~/Library hold the Opt key down while clicking on the Go menu in Finder and a new menu item to open that folder will appear.

Comment: Are your sure about deleting 2016? If I do so, I can't run `mktexlsr` nor `updmap-sys`. Also, after unzipping emerald, where should I put the files? there is no map folder. I've created one and placed them there and the errors gone but still missing the package if I run my code.

Comment: Delete ~/Library/texlive/2016 NOT /usr/local/texlive/2016 which contains the TeX Live 2016 Distribution.

Comment: There is no such folder as `~/Library/texlive/2016` I only have `~/Library/Tex/`.

Comment: You are not looking in ~/Library but in /Library. I told you what to do to open ~/Library above.

Comment: I'm sorry but no such folder.

Comment: If there really is no ~/Library/texlive folder are you sure your ran `updmap`?  Where did you put the emerald.map file? Did you run `sudo -H mktexlsr` after installing the files in the proper sub-directories of /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local? Did you run `sudo -H updmap-sys`?

Comment: Let me add... how did you install TeX Live on your system? Did you use the MacTeX.pkg installer package?

Comment: I've used this `mactex-20161009.pkg`. I've run `udpmap` and `sudo -H mktexlsr`. I've put `emerald.map` inside `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips`. I don't have map and dvips. I just created them to follow the tutorial in the sample section. I've also put it inside `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map` with no luck.

Comment: Wait, you said you put emerald.sty in /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map? The .sty file needs to go into /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/emerald. What did you do with the .fd files, the font files, etc?

Comment: Please ignore my comment regarding putting .sty. I've unzipped the file and put the contents of these files in their corresponding subdirectories in `.../texmf-local/..`

Comment: Where did you put the updmap.cfg file? Did you run `sudo -H mktexlsr` after placing all the files? Did you then run `sudo -H updmap-sys`? Did you really run `updmap`? Could you startup TeXShop and Quit (this will generate a TeXShop folder in ~/Library) and then check to see that the TeXShop folder is, indeed in ~/Library?

Comment: I have `updmap.cfg` inside `.../texmf-local/web2c`. I've run `sudo -H mktexlsr` and `sudo -H updmap-sys`. Running TeXShop did generate the folder in `~/Library`.

Comment: After running this `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map emerald.map`, the problem has been solved.

Comment: Hmmm... having the proper updmap.cfg file in .../texmf-local/web2c and running `sudo -H updmap-sys` should be all you need to do.

Comment: @CroCo: could you let me see your updmap.cfg file?

Comment: As stated in the pdf you've posted but this has nothing to do with the problem. As I mentioned that this line `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map emerald.map` solved the problem but I don't know why.

Comment: @CroCo: I'm trying to figure out why that updmap.cfg, running `sudo -H mktexlsr` and then simply running `sudo -H updmap-sys` didn't work.